# Group results by date range

Tags: postgresql, date, group-by, timestamp, range

I have a table with a `timestamp` column in PostgreSQL and need to count interactions for 24 hours intervals. Sample data:

```
CREATED
-----------------
2019-04-03 17:20:50
2019-04-03 17:20:59
2019-04-03 18:41:18
2019-04-04 09:58:49
2019-04-04 09:58:53
2019-04-04 09:58:59
2019-04-04 10:01:55
2019-04-04 14:52:52
2019-04-04 15:10:43
2019-04-04 15:10:53
2019-04-04 17:15:39
```

Expected result:

```
MIN(CREATED)            MAX(CREATED)          TOTAL
2019-04-03 17:20:50     2019-04-04 17:15:39   11
```

I currently have this script where I convert the date to seconds but I get the following:

```
SELECT
    TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' +
    INTERVAL '1 second' * trunc(extract('epoch' from created) / 86400) * 86400 as filtro,
    min(created),
    max(created),
    count(*)
FROM whts
GROUP BY filtro
ORDER BY max(created) desc;

FILTRO                      MIN(CREATED)                MAX(CREATED)                TOTAL
2019-04-04 00:00:00.000000  2019-04-04 09:58:49.000000  2019-04-04 17:15:39.000000  8
2019-04-03 00:00:00.000000  2019-04-03 17:20:50.000000  2019-04-03 18:41:18.000000  3
```

It should return a single row as the first `created` was: *2019-04-03 17:20:50* and the last *2019-04-04 17:15:39*. No **24 hours** have passed.

Comment: Your query has 5 columns while your expected output only has 3.  What is your actual desired output?

Comment: I have updated the result I get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT min(created)
     , max(created)
     , count(*)
FROM   whts
GROUP  BY date_trunc('day', created - time '17:20:50')  -- time of the start
ORDER  BY max(created) DESC;
```

The basic trick is to deduct the time component of the start (shift values to fit the daily grid), then you can just use [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) to form groups.

The best way to identify the offset depends on the missing definition of the task ... where to start or end this?

To just start with the earliest `created` in the table:

```
SELECT min(created)
     , max(created)
     , count(*)
FROM   whts, (SELECT min(created)::time FROM whts) t(t_start)
GROUP  BY date_trunc('day', created - t.t_start) 
ORDER  BY max(created) DESC;
```

Comment: Nice answer Erwin +1.  Do you get a present for breaking 350K?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use trunc function as this for your required result.
Maybe you can try something as follow:
    trunc((extract('epoch' from (created-(select min(created) from whts)) / 86400) * 86400

Comment: When making this adjustment. I have 11 data as results when I only get one, nothing more

(https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c6c3158131892823524a4584afceae0b)